# Recursively append over nested list python

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to recursively append to a list while iterating over a nested list. For example, if I have a list `[['a',['b',['c','d']]]]`, I would like a function to return `[['a','b','c'],['a','b','d']]`. My attempt so far is the following:

```
def recurse_append(data):
    r_list=[]
    for elem in data:
        if isinstance(elem, list):
            r_list.extend(recurse_append(elem))
        else:
            r_list.append(elem)
    return r_list
```

which for this example returns `['a','b','c','d']`. Unlike the example, the nested list that I am writing this for does not contain the same number of elements at each level, so I thought that a recursive function would be the best way to take this into account. Any help towards a solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the expected output of `[a,[b,c],d,[e,f]]`? `[[a,b,d,e],[a,b,d,f],[a,c,d,e],[a,c,d,f]]`?

Comment: Your code doesn't work as you expected because you are flattening all nested lists. Note that it will run recursively while there is any list inside the main list. You need do define a sort of nesting level that will limit the flattening to a certain point.